# Non inverting differentiator

Tags: analog

Could anybody help in providing circuit for non inverting differentiator. Why is this not very popular? I am not able to find resources on the web.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what specifically you mean? You can build a non-inverting differentiator out of a capacitor and resistor, and these high pass RC filters are very common.

Answer (score 3):

Although your description is very vague, maybe this circuit suits your needs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwBf6R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function is: $$ T(s)=\frac{V_2(s)}{V_1(s)}=\frac{R_1R_4-R_2R_3}{R_1(R_3+R_4)}+s\frac{CR_2R_4}{R_3+R_4}$$

The resource of this schematic can be found at the following [link](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_sdt=0%2C5&btnG=&hl=nl&inst=6833560761083429746&q=A%20non-inverting%20differentiator%20using%20a%20single%20operational%20amplifier).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for your input. I have changed the schematic.

Comment: I agree that my question was vague. Well I was looking into the circuit of practical differentiators from the link https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/analog-integrated-circuits/opampdifferentiator/practical-differentiator/. I was interested to convert this circuit with non inverting configuration

Comment: @gari it's great to  recognize your question isn't perfect (nothing ever is), but in recognition of what you've clearly left out, please **edit** your question to include links and information.

Comment: The benefit of the circuit I proposed is that the input resistance is pure resistive. Meaning, that the circuit you want to differentiate doesn't need to provide current to charge the capacitor. For more information, have a look at the link I have added. Don't forget to mark this answer as useful if my answer has helped you.

Comment: Another useful reference/paper on the topic https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/45a7/9f2384a0b692f54b8b199834bd882b8f4da6.pdf